# Iterating content of listbox silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, listbox

I have a listbox

```
 <ListBox Width="400" Height="150" x:Name="QuestionsBox" Margin="0,0,0,40">
            <ListBoxItem Name="Item1" Content="Hello"></ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Name="Item2" Content="Hello"></ListBoxItem>

</ListBox>
```

I want to display the content of the item in the listbox when it is selected. Like, if the user selects Item1 then I should be able to get the Content - Hello

I tried using the SelectedItem property `[QuestionsBox.SelectedItem]` but I don't seem to get the value of the content at the run time.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=QuestionsBox}" />
```